Door to garage is 1.5in above the floor, and that space is unfinished wood. Wondering what I should put in there
So we moved into a house and the old owners put in a garage door themselves. There was a kind of a sils on it that was beaten up so we want to get something to make it look fairly normal.
I was thinking of just trying to get a piece of wood and paint it the same colour as the baaseboard to cover that up. Was just wondering if there are any other thoughts.
The dimensions of that gap from the rubber on the bottom of the door to the brown-ish wood part is 1.5in high and about 5/8 in deep. It goes about 32 1/4 inch across.
I'm also going to replace the moulding around the door at the same time as there is a bit of agap as you can see in the photo.
I've seen people suggest thresholds and other stuff, but that seemed weird to me given that this is 1.5in high.
Happy to provide any other info :)




it is missing a threshold
